# Passing parameters to Twig extension from template?

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I use Twig extension to pass global variables from the database like in the code below. But I want to make this more dynamic to get data from database by the `id` parameter ..

**service**

```
app.twig.database_globals_extension:
 class: Coursat\CoursatBundle\Twig\Extension\DatabaseGlobalsExtension
 arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
 tags:
     - { name: twig.extension }
```

**extension**

```
<?php

namespace Coursat\CoursatBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class DatabaseGlobalsExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

   protected $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
   {
      $this->em = $em;
   }

   public function getGlobals()
   {
      return array (
              "myVariable" => $this->em->getRepository('CoursatBundle:test')->find(##I want to pass a var here from the template##),
      );
   }

   public function getName()
   {
      return "CoursatBundle:DatabaseGlobalsExtension";
   }

}
```

**template**

```
{{ myVariable.name() }}
```

Comment: Add an extra Twig_SimpleFunction in which you can pass the `key` as parameters and just do sthing like `function($key) { return $this->getGlobals()[$key]; } `

Comment: Hi , please can you explain more :)

Comment: See the answer I've created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very bad idea to store this in your globals, because your database will be requested for each calls of your website.

You can use a function to retrieve those data:

```
<?php

namespace Coursat\CoursatBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class DatabaseGlobalsExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

   protected $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
   {
      $this->em = $em;
   }

   public function getFunctions()
   {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('my_test', array($this, 'myTest')),
        );
   }

   public function myTest($id)
   {
      return $this->em->getRepository('CoursatBundle:test')->find($id);
   }

   public function getName()
   {
      return "CoursatBundle:DatabaseGlobalsExtension";
   }

}
```

Then in your Twig template, use this to load your entity:

```
{% set twigVar = my_test(42) %}
```

This is still a bad practice though, you should load your entities in your controllers, not in your views.

Comment: OMG it's really amaizing :) !

Comment: Hi bro , why this is bad practice ? And if I need a global variable such as 'site name' which stored in database (Like WordPress)

Comment: @hassen-zouari, two concerns here really.  First, in an MVC design  (separation of concerns), the controller handles data access, the view should just render. Second, hitting the database for data not used = wasted cycles.  The second may not be a problem using Doctrine, if you have to load the entity anyway somewhere else in the application (ie: an user object), or it is cached, thereby skipping a DB call.

Answer (score 1):

```
class DatabaseGlobalsExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    ...
    ...
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
             'get_db_global', function($key) {
                  $globals = $this->getGlobals();
                  return isset($globals[$key]) ? $globals[$key] : null;
              }
        );
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Inside twig :

```
   The global with key "Foo" is : {{ get_db_global('foo') }}
```

Comment: Thanks But it shows ##Notice: Undefined variable: key##

Comment: Hi , thanks bro for helping but this doesn't work as well as I want ... please can I contact you in skype ? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> *If the question is "**Passing parameters to Twig extension from template?**"*

E.g. for *Filters*

```
//... 
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class SomeFilterExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

  public function getFilters()
  {
    return [
        new TwigFilter('someFilter', [$this, 'someFilter']),
    ];
}

public function someFilter(mixed $baseValue,mixed $mandatoryParam,mixed $optionalParam = null): mixed
{
    // ....
    return $baseValue;
}
```

}

Inside templates:

```
// ...
{{ blaBlaBlaValue|someFilter(mandatoryParam) }}
// ...
```

or

```
// ...
{{ blaBlaBlaValue|someFilter(mandatoryParam,optionalParam) }}
// ...
```

Look at -> [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)